# Changing ruby version disables rails and bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm following along with Michael Hartl's R-o-R tutorial. Having hit a problem, I got the good advice on SO to grab Hartl's reference code from github, which I've done.

However, when following his instructions to get the reference code set up in a tmp directory, I can either rbenv version 2.1.1, in which case I get a conflict with the gem file, or go with Ruby version 2.0.0-p451 as in the gem file, in which case neither bundler nor rails will run. I get the following (for example) -

```
Dans-MacBook-Air:sample_app_rails_4 dan$ rails

Your Ruby version is 2.1.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0

Dans-MacBook-Air:sample_app_rails_4 dan$ rbenv local 2.0.0-p451
Dans-MacBook-Air:sample_app_rails_4 dan$ rbenv rehash
Dans-MacBook-Air:sample_app_rails_4 dan$ bundler install

rbenv: bundler: command not found

The `bundler' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.1.1

Dans-MacBook-Air:sample_app_rails_4 dan$
```

I could just change the ruby version in the gemfile, but I'm trying to track down another bug so I want to replicate the original exactly.

Thanks for reading this - any ideas? When I installed rails etc, I was working with Ruby 2.1.1 - has this caused the problem?

Comment: You will need to install rails again for that version of ruby as each ruby has its own directory and gem path. Effectively, when you install gems on a ruby version, they are stored under that specific version. If you find yourself changing versions frequently, you can manage gemsets using [rbenv-gemset](https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset). My personal preference is RVM though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each version of ruby has its own gemset. You'll have to install bundler again for each version of Ruby.

Comment: I guess that means installing rubygems again as well? - can answer this for myself, no, you don't need to install rubygems again.